# Should I use group by to make this query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So I have this table in my rails app:

```
create_table "scores", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "points"
  t.integer  "exercise_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "attempt_number"
  t.boolean  "complete"
  t.integer  "count_hints"
  t.text     "attempt_content"
  t.integer  "seed"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "time_taken"
  t.integer  "tutor_session_id"
  t.integer  "problem_id"
end
```

The context: Students work on problems that are uniquely identified by an EXERCISE_ID, PROBLEM_ID and SEED.

When a student works on a problem, any answer that is submitted will be stored in this scores table. The answer will be stored, how long it took them for that attempt, what attempt number they're on, whether that answer was correct, etc. Once they answer the correct answer, they can move on to the next problem.

What I would like to do, for a given user, is to retrieve the scores but grouped together by the given exercise_id, problem_id and seed.

I would like to have returned an array and each element is another array of all the attempts and whatnot around a given exercise_id, problem_id and seed.

I've been trying to use GROUP BY exercise_id, problem_id and seed, but if I don't use some sort of aggregator like count or sum, I don't really get back results that match what I want.

Is this sort of query grouping possible?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One of the properties of SQL is that it is *compositional*. This means that the result of performing a `SELECT` on a relation is also a relation. In other words, querying a table will return another table.

The `GROUP BY` operation ensures just this, and as you pointed out, it only works with aggregating functions. Because of this, SQL itself can not give you a set of relations.

It is very possible to achieve this in Ruby, though. Have a look at the `Enumerable` module, and `#group_by` in particular.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html